# How do I retrieve a string dumped into stdin in PyQT?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, barcode, keypress

I have a dialog open that is waiting for a barcode to be entered from the barcode scanner.
If I had the keyboard focus on a `LineEdit` widget, the barcode would simply be inserted into the field. But I don't want to have that setup. I just want a dialog to wait for the code to arrive and when it has received one, return back to the main window.

I tried making a timer that checked for the inputs in `stdin` every second, but that didn't work.

```
def handleTimeout(self):
    inp = sys.stdin.readline()
    print('You pressed {}'.format(str(inp)))
```

I didn't look further into it, as i figured there has to be some better, more efficient way anyway.

How do I proceed?
I want to read the 13 byte bar-code, that I receive from the scanner.

---

**EDIT**

```
def keyPressEvent(self, event):
         if type(event) == QtGui.QKeyEvent:
             stt = chr(event.key())
             if (not stt.isdigit()): return
             self.barcode += chr(event.key())
             print(self.barcode)
             if (len(self.barcode) == 13): self.close()
             event.accept()
         else:
             event.ignore()
```

It works actually. but I can see a ton of things that can go wrong. Like a user could press a key or two before the scanning began. How do I correct those? Could i just capture events from the scanner, and not any keyboard?

Comment: Surely the scanner puts its data in a memory buffer, no? The scanner only generates keyboard events?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [spontaneous](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qevent.html#spontaneous) method of the event to test whether the keypress came from outside the application.

Comment: I just tried and it returns `false` for both keypresses and data from barcode scanner. Looks like the barcode scanner only mimics a keyboard input (or maybe it's only this particular model).
Anyway, my current solution is: when a valid keypress event occurs, a timer is started for 200 milliseconds. If it receives the remaining digits within that time frame, then it accepts the input. Else it resets `stt`. A keyboard wouldn't normally allow that many keypresses in such short time.

Comment: @ShashwatBlack. Seems reasonable. I've also read elsewhere that it's possible to configure scanners to emit a prefix signature before the actual barcode.